# relationship between products and stock entieies

Tags: mysql, database, t-sql, database-design, relational-database

I'm developing a stock control database and wish to know what would be the best way to do relationship between `products` and `stocks` entities.

Which of below is appropriate? If none, please let me know why and what is your suggestion.

Thanks in advance

**PRODUCTS - STOCKS**

Based on above entities:

- If I have `1:1` relationship, looks like I'll have to reduce stock
  amount in same row by updating the row with `UPDATE` statement.
- If I have `1:n` relationship, looks like I'll have to add a new row
  with updated stock amount in it with `INSERT` statement.

**IMPORTANT POINTS**

- There will be concurrent users to manipulate stock like increasing and/or reducing so `[ACID][1]` is important point.
- `Stock amount` is non-negative value.

Comment: @MitchWheat Why did you vote to close the question as "not a real question"? This is not exactly the most original question ever, but it is definitely a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you need a simple **number** that describes the available quantity of a product, just store it as a field in the product table. Updating it in a single statement is atomic:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET AMOUNT = AMOUNT + <change>
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = <whatever>
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT AMOUNT
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = <whatever>
FOR UPDATE;

(Calculate new amount.)

UPDATE PRODUCT
SET AMOUNT = <new amount>
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = <whatever>;

COMMIT;
```

Note the FOR UPDATE which locks the row until the COMMIT and prevents the anomalies that would otherwise be possible in a concurrent environment.

Without FOR UPDATE, just the regular ACID guarantees are not enough. For example:

- The transaction **A** SELECTs the current AMOUNT, let's say it's 5.
- The transaction **B** SELECTs the current AMOUNT, which is still 5 because no other transaction has committed any change yet.
- The transaction **A** adds 2 to the amount, resulting in 7.
- The transaction **B** adds 3 to the amount, resulting in 8.
- The transaction **A** UPDATEs the row to 7 and commits.
- The transaction **B** UPDATEs the row to 8 and commits.

Suddenly, the resulting AMOUNT in the table is 5 + 3 = 8, even though it should have been 5 + 2 + 3 = 10. One of the changes is lost - whoever commits last wins.

---

If you need a history of product amounts, or need to track individual "instances" of products, then yes, you'd need a separate table in a 1:N relationship, which may have its own locking challenges in the concurrent environment.

---

> Stock amount is non-negative value.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints, but for this specific case, you can simply use one of the [UNSIGNED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html) data types.

Comment: I was reading lockings in `dev.mysql.com` site and found out that what you say is the way to go. So the result is `1:1` with `FOR UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

it `depends` on the `no. of users updating/inserting rows` for particular product,also `depends on` what your system can bear memory overhead or performance

**in updation**
in `mysql - update needs write lock` ,
so ,**performance drain:** for many users the system would be as compared slow  
**in insert**
**memory drain:** say for 100 user 100 rows may be for more updates 100 rows.

i think `1:1 relation ship is better` because
 if you are giving `1:n` relation ship then,

for increasing the stock:

```
-you 'll add new row .
-so for total stock 
       - you have to add all the subsequent rows,if new value you are inserting 
         is only the incremented amt 
       - or if it is the total increased amt the previous rows would not have
         any significance.
```

for decreasing the stock,
same ,

```
-if the total decrement amt you are inserting then the previous data has 
 no significance,
-but if only decrement value is there , so for every user you have to put 
 a check over the total stock which you would get from many rows.
```